# What is the probability that the number of heads is equal to the number showing on the die?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For this question, I know how to calculate the sample space, but I'm not sure how to use permutations or combinations. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Suppose we roll one fair six-sided die, and flip six coins. What is the probability that the number of heads is equal to the number showing on the die?

$S = 6 + 2^6 = 70$

$P(1H, 1) = \frac{7!}{5!2!*70}$

$P(2H, 2) = \frac{7!}{4!3!70}$

$P(3H, 3) = \frac{7!}{4!3!*70}$

$P(4H, 4) = \frac{7!}{5!2!*70}$

$P(5H, 5) = \frac{7!}{6!*70}$

$P(6H, 6) = \frac{7!}{70}$

$ Total = P(1H, 1) + P(2H, 2) + P(3H, 3) +P(4H, 4) +P(5H, 5) + P(6H, 6)$

Comment: For a start, $S=6\cdot 2^6 = 384$. Then you can't arrange the die into the coins, so you should be choosing your head-facing coins from $6$, not $7$

Answer (score 3):

The sample space is the product of the sample spaces for the dice and the coins.  If you order the coins the space is $6 \cdot 2^6=384$

Now consider the number of ways to get each total of heads from $1$ to $6$.  They should add to $63$ because you don't consider the $1$ way to get no heads.  For each of them there is one favorable roll of the die, so there are $63$ favorable combinations.  The probability is then $$\frac {63}{384}=\frac {21}{128}$$

Comment: So the way to get heads would be total subtract the one way to get no heads?

Comment: Can you explain more about where the 63 came from?

Comment: There are $2^6=64$ tosses of six coins if you consider order.  One of those has no heads and cannot match the die.

Comment: So then what about the probability for rolling the die?

Comment: We are counting successful combinations. For each of the $63$rolls there is one roll of the die, so there are $63$ total successful combinations.

Comment: Ok, so let me get this straight. There is 64 total combinations for six coins. There is one way to get no heads, which also means there is no way to get a number for the die. 64-1 is the number of ways which we can get a head from 1 to 6, and the chance of getting a number on each die is the same, which is where the 63 came from, right?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Ok, now this makes sense to me, thanks

Comment: An alternative presentation is $\dfrac{63}{64} \times \dfrac16$ for the probability you get at least $1$ head, multiplied by the conditional probability that the die then matches the number of heads

Comment: Yes, that is also a good way to do this, thanks

Comment: @Henry: Dang, I was just about to post your comment as an answer, and here you've gone and posted my answer as a comment! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Binomial coefficients $\large 7\choose k$ for different values of $k$, which would be relevant if you were repeating some binary experiment $7$ times identically and independently, which you are not. One of your seven experiments is drastically different from the others. It *is* independent from the other six though, which means that you may compute probabilities separately and multiply them in the end ($P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ for independent events $A,B$).

Bottom line: use the binomial approach for the coin and then multiply with the probability of getting a given number when you roll a dice.